# Automatically refresh screen on android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app and on one screen it shows orders pulled from a database. These orders usually have a few items in them.

I can pull the data and display it with no issues, however I am struggling to implement a means of automatically refreshing the activity so that new orders are displayed (for example a refresh every 15 seconds).

I had played around with a handler and running the displayOrders() method every 15 seconds but that resulted in the same orders being posted again every 15 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
public class ChefScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    List<ChefOrderList> listOrders;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chef_screen);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_chef_orders);
        listOrders = new ArrayList<>();

        displayOrders();
    }

    private void displayOrders(){
        String url = "hidden";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("orders");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject orderObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        ChefOrderList c = new ChefOrderList(orderObj.getString("menu_item_name"), orderObj.getString("item_type"), orderObj.getString("order_date_time"),
                                orderObj.getInt("quantity_ordered"), orderObj.getInt("order_id"));
                        listOrders.add(c);


                    }
                    ChefOrderAdapter adapter = new ChefOrderAdapter(listOrders, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ChefScreen.this, "Oops!" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("menuid", "0");
                return params;
            }

        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

The adapter:

```
 private List<ChefOrderList> chefOrderList1;
    private Context context;
    private Button completeOrder;


    public ChefOrderAdapter(List<ChefOrderList> M, Context C){
        super(C, R.layout.listcheforders, M);
        this.chefOrderList1 = M;
        this.context = C;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcheforders,null,true);

        TextView orderNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.tvOrderNumber);
        TextView itemType = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemType);
        TextView itemName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
        TextView orderQuantity = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemQty);
        TextView orderTime = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDateTime);



        completeOrder = view.findViewById(R.id.btnComplete);




        ChefOrderList chefOrderList = chefOrderList1.get(position);


        itemName.setText(chefOrderList.getName());
        orderQuantity.setText("Qty: " +chefOrderList.getQty());


        if(position>0){
            ChefOrderList prevChefOrderList = chefOrderList1.get(position-1);
            if(chefOrderList.getOrder() != (prevChefOrderList.getOrder())){
                orderNumber.setText("Order: " +chefOrderList.getOrder());
                orderTime.setText(chefOrderList.getDate());
                completeOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                completeOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        completeOrder(position);
                    }
                });

            }

            if(!chefOrderList.getType().equals(prevChefOrderList.getType())){
                itemType.setText(chefOrderList.getType());
            }

        } else {

            itemType.setText(chefOrderList.getType());
            orderNumber.setText("Order: " +chefOrderList.getOrder());
            orderTime.setText(chefOrderList.getDate());
            completeOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            completeOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    completeOrder(position);
                }
            });

        }
        return view;

    }

    private void completeOrder(final int position){
        String url = "http://mgourley03.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/RestaurantApp/clearOrder.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Order completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Clear order failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error!" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("orderid", String.valueOf(chefOrderList1.get(position).getOrder()));
                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

Is anyone able to suggest a means of getting the activity to refresh every 15 seconds and only show a list of individual orders (as opposed to showing some orders every time it refreshes)

Comment: Are the same order shown, or the new orders came with the latest request is appended to the already shown orders

Comment: This is not how it should be done. Instead of polling the database every 15 seconds, one should get notified when the data is inserted in the database and update the UI accordingly thereafter. You could have a `BroadcastReceiver` notify the UI after new data was inserted in the DB, or, the modern way (but a bit more ellaborate) of handling this scenario would be to use `Room` and `LiveData`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could handle this scenario but to start I would use a cursor adapter to list your data.

1. You can then use a content provider and content observer and notify whenever the data is changed
2. You could use Room and live data
3. You could use SqlBrite and observe on updates to the table then notify your adapter to be reloaded